# R - rbind logically

Tags: r, reshape, rbind

I have this dataframe:

```
source_data <- data.frame(
    "date" = c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-02-01", "2018-02-01"), 
    "nr" = c(0, 1, 0, 1),
    "marketing_fees" = c(500, 600, 800, 900),
    "services_paid" = c(40, 50, 10, 30),
    stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Result should look like this

```
result <- data.frame(
  "date" = c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-02-01", "2018-02-01", "2018-02-01", "2018-02-01"), 
  "nr" = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
  "income" = c(500, 40, 600, 50, 800, 10, 900, 30),
  "source" = c("marketing", "services", "marketing", "services", "marketing", "services", "marketing", "services"),
  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Only way how can I do is this

```
result <- rbind(
  source_data %>% 
    filter(date == "2018-01-01") %>% 
    select(date, nr, income = marketing_fees) %>% 
    mutate(source = "marketing"),

  source_data %>% 
    filter(date == "2018-01-01") %>% 
    select(date, nr, income = services_paid) %>% 
    mutate(source = "services"),

  source_data %>% 
    filter(date == "2018-02-01") %>% 
    select(date, nr, income = marketing_fees) %>% 
    mutate(source = "marketing"),

  source_data %>% 
    filter(date == "2018-02-01") %>% 
    select(date, nr, income = services_paid) %>% 
    mutate(source = "services")
)
```

Code above is not just ugly with lot of repeated parts, I can't use it anymore this way sice my dataframe has about 50 columns and lot of dataes. How would you achieve result dataframe without so much repeated codes?

Comment: This is reshaping and some elementary text processing as far as I can see. will post an answer as a proof.

Comment: Note that this is similar to the logic of reopening mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56662593/retrieve-values-of-the-data-frame-by-matching-id-and-column-name/56662713#56662713)  I don't see any difference.  Rules should be similar to everybody and not for somebody else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `gather` to reshape from 'wide' to 'long' and then `separate` the column name to return only the prefix part

```
library(tidyverse)
source_data %>% 
    gather(source, income, marketing_fees:services_paid) %>% 
    separate(source, into = c('source', 'extra')) %>%
    select(-extra) %>% 
    arrange(date, nr)
#        date nr    source income
#1 2018-01-01  0 marketing    500
#2 2018-01-01  0  services     40
#3 2018-01-01  1 marketing    600
#4 2018-01-01  1  services     50
#5 2018-02-01  0 marketing    800
#6 2018-02-01  0  services     10
#7 2018-02-01  1 marketing    900
#8 2018-02-01  1  services     30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
result2 <- melt(
  setDT(source_data), 
  id.vars = c("date", "nr"), 
  value.name = "income", 
  variable.name = "source"
)[, source := sub("_.*", "", source)][order(date, nr)]°

         date nr    source income
1: 2018-01-01  0 marketing    500
2: 2018-01-01  0  services     40
3: 2018-01-01  1 marketing    600
4: 2018-01-01  1  services     50
5: 2018-02-01  0 marketing    800
6: 2018-02-01  0  services     10
7: 2018-02-01  1 marketing    900
8: 2018-02-01  1  services     30
```